# Shell script invocation error xcode 4.5.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

when i am trying to run my app on device i got the following error.

```
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.0'.
```

After changing any ios sdk in build settings to iPhone Developer now am getting the following error.

```
/Users/chandrasekhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnitConverter-
dhznawqrnkbqwvcrkgpzpkjmooox/Build/Intermediates/UnitConverter.build/Debug-
iphoneos/UnitConverter.build/Script-50524F424C454D533F.sh: line 4: 
/Library/JailCoder/Entitlements/Entitlements.py: No such file or directory
```

help me solve this error. Reinstalling Xcode is not working

Comment: Perhaps `/Library/JailCoder/Entitlements/Entitlements.py` should be `~/Library/...`.  What is `Entitlements.py`; something you wrote?

Comment: no i didnt write anything with that name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Jailcoder again and Unpatch the project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the script is using [JailCoder](http://jailcoder.com/), which doesn't appear to be installed (or requires re-installing).

Comment: @ChandraSekhar At some point JailCoder has been installed on that machine and has possibly patched Xcode (yuck!).  Or possibly it was (is) used in the Xcode project. Are you saying that isn't the case?

Comment: ya i used it once. but now i have a valid cert. and i am not using jailcoder any more.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar Sounds like you need to remove Xcode and reinstall it as JailCoder has messed with it.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar No idea - you need to undo what JailCoder did, so perhaps ask them for help?

Answer (score 0):

got It! I couldn't get jailcoder to unpatch so what you must do is go into the build phases and remove the part that inserts jailcoder into the build phase pretty easy once you take the time to dig into the guts of the app!